# scanner.nextLine() not working like I think it does

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am creating a random name generator for a fantasy table top game I play with my friends. Everything is working so for, except for when I go to scan a nextLine() for my description, the program doesn't wait for input, and instead goes back to the start of the while loop. What I want to do, is be able to type in a short sentence about the character they are interacting with, and have it set to the String value Description, later my goal is to print these values out in a text document as I create them for future use. My code for that section looks like as follows. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    System.out.println("Male (m) Female (f) Quit (q)");
    ui = UserInput.next();
    while(!(ui.equals("q"))){
        if(ui.equals("m")){
            mName = maleNameGenerator(MS, SS, MaleNamesArray, SurnamesArray);
            System.out.println(mName);
            System.out.print("Location: ");
            Location = UserInput.next();
            System.out.print("Profession: ");
            Profession = UserInput.next();
            System.out.print("Description: ");
            Description = UserInput.nextLine();
        }
        else if(ui.equals("f")){
            fName = femaleNameGenerator(FS, SS, FemaleNamesArray, SurnamesArray);
            System.out.println(fName);
        }
        else if(!(ui.equals("q"))){
            System.out.println("Please input valid choice.");
        }
        System.out.println("Male (m) Female (f) Quit (q)");
        ui = UserInput.next();
        ui.toLowerCase();
    }
    UserInput.close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

Comment: What is the code of `UserInput`? You talk about a `Scanner` here but there's no scanner in the code you've provided. For better help sooner, post a [mcve] to make the problem more easily reproducible for those seeking to help you.

Comment: You should respect the conventional CamelCase. For one moment, I thought `UserInput` was a class whereas I now understand it's just an instance of `Scanner`. Using CamelCase will make your programs more readable for every programmer

Comment: @durron597 it must be an instance of `Scanner`, but I have first had the same reaction as you

Comment: @Dici Oh, he used a capitalized variable name for something not a class. Duh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `next()` method leaves behind a newline character after taking input. In your code, the `nextLine()` method simply consumes this newline character and ignores the actual input. You can add another `nextLine()` to make sure the input is received.

```
...
System.out.print("Description: ");
UserInput.nextLine();
Description = UserInput.nextLine();
```

This problem can also occur when using other non-String type Scanner input methods (`nextInt()`, `nextDouble()`, etc). The explanation and solution would be the same.

Comment: Just a note, `.nextInt()` (and other non String typed methods) also leave the newline character in the buffer too.

Comment: @anditpainsme Thanks for the note!